# Change opacity of a TreeItem

Tags: gwt

I have a server and client using gwt.
In my client page i have a tree item displayed.

I want to do one of the following:
   -  disable the tree item when a function is called.
   -  made opaque the entire client page  or only the tree item when a function is called.

By made opaque, i want to do the same as occur when i debug my project with eclipse and i stop and i get the following in the client page

GWT Code Server Disconnected
Most likely, you closed GWT Development Mode. Or, you might have lost network connectivity. To fix this, try restarting GWT Development Mode and REFRESH this page.

Please give me some indication on how to do it and if it is possible.

Comment: did you try with css addStyleName(yourstyle)?

Comment: I want to do it programatically. Is this the way?

Comment: you can apply the style at runtime. in the called function you just make something like item.addStyleName("yourstyle");

Answer (score 1):

you create a handler for you function call(s) and add the style when the funciton is called. Because GWT works with javascript it changes your appearance during runtime.

```
item.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
             event.getItem().setStyleName("newStyle");
        }            
    });
```

and in the css you define you style:

```
newStyle: {
      ...
      your style definition
}
```